# Domain masking emergency

Tags: html, iframe

I would never normally do this, but 1and1 have been experiencing a "glitch" with their system that means you can't add new external domains. It's pretty shocking, to be honest, and unfortunately my client's site needs to go live under their old domain ASAP.

The only solution is to temporarily set up an iframe domain mask... but how best to do this? My attempts don't seem to be working properly (the iframe doesn't fill the screen).

Please help me with this crappy solution until 1and1 get their act together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use an `<iframe>` when a regular `<frameset>` will do.

(This is untested as I haven't used frames in more then a decade).

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A Basic Example of Frames</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET ROWS="1%, *">
     <FRAME SRC="index.html">
     <FRAME SRC="http://www.otherdomain.com">
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

***Warning*** this is not search engine friendly. Doing this for an extended period of time will have negative consequences for their rankings.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I know it's pure evil and will do them harm in the long run, but hopefully this won't be for more than a couple of days. Very annoying, though.

Comment: Good luck! And maybe one day find a host that doesn't have issues like this. That's just absurd.

Comment: 1and1 have a great reputation, or so I've heard. Pretty amazing this part of their functionality could go down for a few days, though.

Comment: Switch from framesets as soon as you can. I'd check and make sure this solution works in major browsers before you use it.  This HTML element has been deprecated for a long time and modern browsers like Chrome might not react well to it.